# Does setting a float value in a style require some special code?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set a value for CornerRadius in a resource that's used by a style and cannot get it to work.  Here is what my code looks like:

C# code:

```
Current.Resources["FrameCornerRadius"] = "25";
followed by many other lines like this which all work okay
```

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="FrameBorder" TargetType="Frame">
    <!-- Following line does not give any corner radius  -->
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{DynamicResource FrameCornerRadius}" />
    <!-- Following line gives corner radius  -->
    <!--<Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="25" />-->
</Style>
```

Xaml

```
<Frame Style="{StaticResource FrameBorder}">
   <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">
      <xaml:ButtonXaml />
   </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

When I set it with `Value="{DynamicResource FrameCornerRadius}"` it doesn't work.  When I set it directly in the style to be 25 it works.  Note that I have 30 or more other Current.Resources that all work good so I don't think that's the problem.

For reference:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Frame.cs

public float CornerRadius { get; set; } << from the specs

Comment: Isn't `FrameCornerRadius` a static resource and not a dynamic resource?

Comment: I think it's okay the way it's set as for example another of the properties: <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource FrameBackgroundColor}" />   is specified there in the style and that works okay.  Just not the FrameCornerRadius

Comment: try using a static resource and see if that works though I have a feeling it should, cause this is not a dynamic resource if i am not wrong

Comment: When I use the word DynamicResource it gives no error but doesn't make a corner.   When I use the word StaticResource it gives this error:  StaticResource not found for key FrameCornerRadius  All other bindings in the app that are similar use DynamicResource so I'm really not sure what's wrong at this point.

Comment: This doesn't work either <Frame Style="{StaticResource FrameBorder}" CornerRadius="{DynamicResource FrameCornerRadius}">

Comment: The other ones that work can you show me one them?

Comment: <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{DynamicResource FrameMargin}" /> and Current.Resources["FrameMargin"] = new Thickness(15, 0);

Comment: I realized my mistake. It should be Current.Resources["FrameCornerRadius"] = 25;  if you would like to create an answer for this then I can accept your answer.

Comment: I have done that you can take a look if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was with defining the Resource which should be like this:

```
Current.Resources["FrameCornerRadius"] = 25;
```

Goodluck